# use both shebang and strict type declaration in PHP 7

Tags: php, command-line-interface, php-7, shebang

I'm writing a command line PHP script with PHP7.

When I put the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/php`) on top of the file, if I add the strict mode with `declare(strict_types=1)`, I get the following error :

> PHP Fatal error:  strict_types declaration must be the very first statement in the script in index.php on line 3

The only way I found to get the strict types working is to remove the shebang line.

Is there a way to use both shebang and strict types or it is a php bug ?

Comment: This should work and does work for me. Please provide a complete script and how you invoke it. Maybe you have accidentally inserted a superfluous newline or similar?

Comment: you're right, there is a new line between the shebang and the php opening tag... i did not see it because i use a plugin to add the shebang line automatically. i feel stupid...

Comment: VTC as simple typo / not reproducible. And this is why we expect an [MCVE] in questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so here is the reason why the strict types declaration did not work : i had a new line between the shebang and the php opening tag.

working example :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

// your code
```

Comment: True and you can place an extra space between `<?php` opening tag & the strict types declaration.